# Create CSR certificate gives unknonwn error 100,22

Tags: ios, keychain, provisioning-profile, csr

I want to create a CSR certificate but in the keychain after setting it's details in Certificate Assistant -> Req a certificate from CA -> Save it disk then continue. After selecting RSA also it gives "unknown Error 100,22". What is the reason for this? I am using OSx 10.9.5 .

Comment: your OS is really old, why don't you upgrade ?

Comment: Do you have the Apple WWDCRA certificate on your Mac? It can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer Is the date / time on the Mac set correctly?